# Spring3 JPA Persistence Exception on entityManagerFactory

Tags: java

I have an application using Spring 3.2.2 and Hibernate 3.6.0.Final. I made some configurations and the app works pretty well on the test environment, using Postgresql, etc.

Junit Stach trace:
 enter code here

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: 
[PersistenceUnit: P_PROJET] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
```

applicationContext.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">
    <bean id="datasource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/projet" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="persistenceUnitManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
        <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="datasource"></property>
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistance.xml">

        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager"></property>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="P_PROJET"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"></property>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
</beans>
```

Persistance.Xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd ">
  <persistence-unit name="P_PROJET" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
  <properties>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
  </properties>
  </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

console stack trace:

```
INFO : org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@4476128: startup date [Mon Apr 07 21:55:10 WET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
        INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
        INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
        INFO : org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource - Loaded JDBC driver: org.postgresql.Driver
        INFO : org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'P_PROJET'
        INFO : org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version - Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.2.0.Final
        INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.6.0.Final
        INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found
        INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : javassist
        INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
        INFO : org.hibernate.ejb.Version - Hibernate EntityManager 3.6.0.Final
        INFO : org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration - Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
            name: P_PROJET
            ...]
        INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated class: com.gestion.projet.entities.EquipeProjet
        INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity com.gestion.projet.entities.EquipeProjet on table EquipeProjet
        INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated class: com.gestion.projet.entities.MembreTache
        INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity com.gestion.projet.entities.MembreTache on table MembreTache
        INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated class: com.gestion.projet.entities.User
        INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity com.gestion.projet.entities.User on table User
        INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated class: com.gestion.projet.entities.Projet
        INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity com.gestion.projet.entities.Projet on table Projet
        INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated class: com.gestion.projet.entities.Phase
        INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity com.gestion.projet.entities.Phase on table Phase
        INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated class: com.gestion.projet.entities.Role
        INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity com.gestion.projet.entities.Role on table Role
        INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated class: com.gestion.projet.entities.Tache
        INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity com.gestion.projet.entities.Tache on table Tache
        INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder - Mapping collection: com.gestion.projet.entities.EquipeProjet.user -> User
        INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder - Mapping collection: com.gestion.projet.entities.User.membretache -> MembreTache
        INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder - Mapping collection: com.gestion.projet.entities.Projet.phases -> Phase
        INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder - Mapping collection: com.gestion.projet.entities.Phase.tache -> Tache
        INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder - Mapping collection: com.gestion.projet.entities.Tache.membreTaches -> MembreTache
        INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring
        INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.search.HibernateSearchEventListenerRegister - Unable to find org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener on the classpath. Hibernate Search is not enabled.
        INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@8c3c315: defining beans [datasource,persistenceUnitManager,entityManagerFactory,transactionManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
```

Comment: That "nested exception" is important. Post the whole stack trace.

Comment: I post all stack trace

Comment: Where are your connection details. Can't see those in Persistence xml

Comment: the connection details is in applicationContext on bean datasource

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the hibernate-search jar.
See http://hibernate.org/search/